# Java MySQL Login System

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, system

I am currently creating an app with the SixthSense Team and I was wondering, how would I go about a form where a user logs in and java communicates with a MySQL server and then with the databases response, open a page page with that users information

I am using Java 7

Thanks,

James

Edit: Enter Username / Password Connects To MySQL Server Checks Credentials Opens Page

Comment: [ask]. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you done some searching? It is not very clear what you are asking. There many ways of doing what you need to do. The question is are you using some framework to connect to database or you need simple connection?

To show information about user, you need to read data from your database, iterate through result set, make an object within each iteration, store data into it, add it into the list, set it as request or session attribute and retrieve it in the view page.

Here is the login form example:

http://www.roseindia.net/quickguide/tomcat/loginform.shtml

Here is connection to the database example:

http://lxuser.tripod.com/apache/jdbc_mysql.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know how I could, say for example, the username on the table would have a user profile picture link, how would I get java to download it

Comment: Store that image in your server directory, show it on page as a link which points you to the for e.g. FileDownloadServlet. Take a look at file download example: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-download-file-from-website-java-jsp/